# What Schema.org type should I use for an in-depth article like a Wikipedia article?

Tags: schema.org

If I have an in-depth article, what schema should I use? I have multiple articles with over 4,500 words written. It's not a news article.

http://schema.org/Article points out this to cover them all, but I suspect that this kind of article is not supported.

Comment: Why do you think that about `Article`? What do you mean with "supported"?

Comment: @unor - I mean that I do not wan't to be punished by Google by giving them wrong information about the website/article. I mean that schema.org is writing this: "An article, such as a news article or piece of investigative report. Newspapers and magazines have articles of many different types". My articles are more like a wikipedia page. My website is not a newspaper nor a magazine. Just a very informative website about various subjects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Article**](https://schema.org/Article) is the right type for any article, which would cover your use case. It's not absolutely necessary to use a subtype. I would recommend you just use the Article type.

Alternatively, you can use [Report](https://schema.org/Report), a subtype of Article, which may be appropriate depending on the style of your ‘article’.